# Restrict user from opening a document that is checked out

Tags: search

Is there a way to restrict users from opening a document when it is checked out by a different user?

I have been having some issues with my colleagues as some of them are not very familiar with SharePoint. They do not realize that the document is checked out already but they are still able to open the document and make changes...however when the close the document it then tells them that the document was not checked out and that their changes cannot be saved.

I would rather just avoid all these problems and restrict them from being able to open the document in the first place.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 2):

Actually you should train the users for how they are supposed to work with SharePoint.

But, for now you can reduce your pain by creating a new `View` and making it as `Default` view. In the view you just need to have one filter as, `Checked Out To` - `is equal to` - `___blank___`. (Refer to the screenshot below)

[image]

Comment: I would probably modify it and add "or" rule to check if it is checked out to [Me] that way you are not hiding it from users that have it checked it out.

Comment: Looks like a good idea...